# Getting request per hour output with on a specific GET URL

Tags: apache-2.4

Need help in capturing an hourly request count specific to login sessions only.

I found a command set online while doing some searches.  The command returns an hourly count of requests found in the access.log.

grep "23/Jan" progolfdeal.com | cut -d[ -f2 | cut -d] -f1 | awk -F: '{print $2":00"}' | sort -n | uniq -c

I was trying to obtain an hourly request count however it returns all type of requests and the count returned is not matching a specific login count that I'm trying to obtain.

Please help with a query that can include the as well the login count specific to the URL found the access.log.  I will see entries in the log pertaining to the website in the following format \mysite\logon.jsp 200 xxxx & that is what I'm trying to count as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a regex to grep to specify initial strings with GET in them:

```
grep [23/Jan*.GET*.progolfdeal.com] | cut -d[ -f2 | cut -d] -f1 | awk -F: '{print $2":00"}' | sort -n | uniq -c
```

Comment: Thank you for the command provided.  What is the exact command after GET*. if the file being accessed is named access.log.003098 ?  Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide input for this command just pipe it to the cat like this
`cat access.log.003098  | grep [23/Jan*.GET*.progolfdeal.com] | cut -d[ -f2 | cut -d] -f1 | awk -F: '{print $2":00"}' | sort -n | uniq -c`

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'm trying to test the count of the instance of the following in the log file, the log file entry value is -

Comment: Thank you very much.  Pls help in modifying the command with capturing the log entry value " app/login.jsp? "   I'm trying to test the count of the login attempt with the log file entry value is -  app/login.jsp?  --- I tried to use the updated command  --- $ cat access.log.003098 | grep [23/Jan*.app/login.jsp?] | cut -d[ -f2 | cut -d] -f1 | awk -F: '{print $2":00"}' | sort -n | uniq -c  --- however it doesn't return the correct count.  It does return all the request count in the log file which is totalling to 120.  Manual count for " app/login.jsp?" will give a total count of three.

Comment: To start with, could you please mark my answer as an answer and vote it up as I feel like I've answered your initial question. You need to understand that when you are doing that 
`grep [23/Jan*.app/login.jsp?]` it returns every line containing **23/Jan** followed by any number of any characters (thats what *. is for) followed by **app/login.jsp?** although caracters like / and ? should be escaped. From here i can't help you without seeing your log file to know how to write proper regex. I think that now, you should learn how to use regex it will make your life easier.

Comment: This regex is not fully correct cause it uses group, if you want to look for different stuff you need to learn how to write regex. One day of learning and it will change your life :)

Comment: Thank you for the info & I have also marked the answer. New to the forums :-)

Comment: Please see sample log entry = x.x.x.x - - [23/Jan/2019:00:02:38 -0600] "GET /app/login.jsp? HTTP/1.1" 200 1788.  I'm able to get the count using this command -- $ cat access.log | grep 'login.jsp? HTTP/1.1" 200' | cut -d[ -f2 | cut -d] -f1 | awk -F: '{print $2":00"}' | sort -n | uniq -c -- i tested several command options while researching & learning it, still having issues when trying to limit the search to the actual date when I'm trying to add 23/Jan so it will only search for the actual date amongst all the logfile sets.  thank you very much.

Comment: You need to specify regex that will get date and type of request you need. First do it without hawk part to see what is returned, you can use regex testeer online to refind your regex :)

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grep-regular-expressions/ here you can find more :)

Comment: (23\/Jan.*\"GET\s\/app\/login\.jsp\?)

Comment: Thank you very much Kamil.  The online references are very helpful.